# Running Multiple Scripts from Startup Folder on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

Wondering if anyone can shed light on this issue I am having.

I have two python scripts which I want to run when anyone logs into the computer. I have added the scripts to the Startup folder for all users. When I log in the scripts should run with pythonw.exe, both scripts have the pyw extension.

When I log in to my own account, it will only start one script. When I log in to a guest account both scripts start fine.

I have checked AV and the script is not being blocked. Both files access a txt file on the C: drive. I have ensured all users have permissions to access the files.

I can run the second script manually and it works as expected but cannot figure out why it will not run at startup on the admin account.

Comment: You should add them to task scheduler instead.

Comment: Do these two scripts have any mutual dependencies? Could the second script be waiting on the first one? The items in your Startup folder are all started one after the other with no waiting for one to complete before starting any others—in other words both could be running at the same time.

Comment: To debug this, switch to using the .py extension and add the shebang `#!python3 -i`. They'll run with an attached console and drop you into the REPL after the script exits normally or fails.

Comment: Yes, both are running at the same time. I added the shebang line and a console for python 2.7 opened. Surely thats not right. The console shows c:\python27\python.exe . I have 2.7 installed. I just dont know why it would run under the guest account without any issues

Comment: And the penny drops.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thanks for the tip about adding the shebang line. I now know what the issue was. I had python2.7 installed also and the scripts were trying to start with this instead of 3.6. The guest account had the files associatted correctly, that why it worked. All good now. Thanks guys.